# Is it possible to do Double mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, .htaccess

So i build a simple MVC app because I want to learn new stuff. Everething thing work but i need to change the url

in my .httacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myMVC/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

And url is http://mySite/myMVC/about

Were about is the controller,but if I move everything in to root it will be

http://mySite/about

but I don't want do .. I want to be

http://mySite/page:about

Now the problem is that I use explode('/',$path)

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

because it is a folder I use the second array and if change it to http://mySite/page:about there is no / ..

I have seen some people to use the prefix of the file name let say : page_about.php

so the URL is http://mySite/myMVC/page/about

but this is still ugly .. any tips

Answer (score 0):

instead of using explode try:

```
preg_split("/:|\//", $path);
```

this will explode by either `:` or `/`.